# В чем отличия $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] и $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']

Tags: php

Привет.В чем отличия этих 2 переменных ?

Увидел только пример

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost:8080'
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost'
```

Отличаются только указанием порта?

Answer (score 4):

А какую-нибудь документацию смотрели?

В [этой](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php) (первая ссылка из гугла по запросу: $_server 'server_name' php) говорится

```
 'SERVER_NAME'
    Имя хоста, на котором выполняется текущий скрипт. Если  скрипт выполняется на виртуальном хосте, здесь будет содержатся имя, определенное для этого виртуального хоста.

 'HTTP_HOST'
    Содержимое заголовка Host: из текущего запроса, если он есть.
```

Т.е. HTTP_HOST это имя на которое направлен запрос, а SERVER_NAME это где он реально выполняется.

Comment: И как они могут отличатся...для меня эти слова одно и тоже..

Comment: Alias в vhost например.

Comment: @SverxnovA, чтобы стало понятней, почитайте, например [вот здесь](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) пункт 14.23